# What was the source of magic used in Grand Magic Games in Fairy Tail?

Tags: fairy-tail

In the grand magic games arc we saw several team events that use a lot of magic events. Which are "Hidden", "Chariot", "Pandemonium", "Naval Battle" and "Battle Royale" etc.

In the world of magic, we see magic circles being used to create these events. For Example, creating the water sphere in Naval Battle or Peripheral Chariots. These may be comparatively easy, however it would require lots of magic power to create thousands of exact clones (Hidden) or 100 monsters of Pandemonium.

So who/which guild/how was used to create these events since they would require an absurd amount of power.

Considering, How powerful would the user be if he can create a monster which can fight on level footing as an S-Class mage? Thousands of clone which may have same power as that of user(?)

Comment: I don't remember where I heard this, so it may be incorrect. But if I recall, wasn't there something about storing magic power and siphoning it over many many years? They could easily accumulate that amount of power from a large enough population given enough time, then just blow it all on the games.

Answer (score 3):

The source of magic power is not explicitly exposed. It is highly unlikely that the source of the magic power was some wizard. If it was a wizard, he must have been an extremely powerful one, one who could easily create phonies that could easily rival an S-class wizard. Having that kind of power is absolutely monstrous. But there was no such presence in the whole city. The city and the palace almost completely got obliterated by Rogue and the dragons and it was all left to the competitor wizards to save the city. The king himself came to request them to save the people. If there was some such wizard who had that kind of power, he should have been with the king and would have joined the battle. No such thing happened.

From all that, the only logical conclusion is that all that magic power is coming from the Eclipse Gate itself. The Eclipse Gate can hold magic power that rivals that of the Etherion. That much magic is simply too much to imagine. Providing a small amount of that power to the magic games each year wouldn't make much of a difference in the immense reservoir of magic.

Comment: Interesting theory. For me it would be something like what Mystogan did. Get enough crystals to create a persona rivalling that of a S-Class like Laxus or Erza. +1 for the exact same train of thought that led me to ask this question. Not correcting it as of yet since its still just a theory and maybe someone else can get some sources for this.

Comment: I appreciate that. It would be great to have more thoughts on this.

Comment: I like the idea, but a team of magicians or Crystals supplying power to a smaller group (possibly 1) Architect would make more sense. They were using eclipse to build up magic power to actually use the gate, so expanding its power would be counterproductive

Comment: @Ryan That could be true indeed but then again, there is the matter of the immense magic power needed for things like Pandemonium. Crystals could definitely be possibility. A wizard or a group of wizards is still kind of unlikely since we didn't see anyone in the final battle except for the competitors.